# Trouble with jhbuild installation while running the command $ jhbuild sanitycheck

Tags: gtk, gnome, jhbuild

I am trying to learn GTK+3 as per this site: https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html. From the page:

> 1.1. Dependencies
>
> - GTK+3
> - Python 2 (2.6 or later) or Python 3 (3.1 or later)
> - gobject-introspection
>
> [...]
>
> The easiest way to install PyGObject from source is using JHBuild. It
> is designed to easily build source packages and discover what
> dependencies need to be build and in what order. To setup JHBuild,
> please follow the JHBuild manual.

I followed the manual as per that link and downloaded via git JHBuild (as they say to do) and built it with make/make install. That went fine. The next step is where the problem begins.
I ran the next command I was supposed to as per the page:

> 2.3. Build Prerequisites
>
> Before any modules can be built, it is necessary to have certain build
> tools installed. Common build tools include the GNU Autotools
> (autoconf, automake, libtool and gettext), The GNU Toolchain
> (binutils, gcc, g++), make, pkg-config and Python, depending on which
> modules will be built.
>
> JHBuild can check the tools are installed using the sanitycheck
> command:
>
> `$ jhbuild sanitycheck`

When I first ran this I got this:

> jhbuild: install prefix (/opt/gnome) can not be created

I ran the following commands and got the results below:

```
daddara@daddara-desktop:~/jhbuild/jhbuild$ sudo chmod 777 /opt/gnome/ -R
chmod: cannot access `/opt/gnome/': No such file or directory
daddara@daddara-desktop:~/jhbuild/jhbuild$ mkdir /opt/gnome
mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/gnome': Permission denied
daddara@daddara-desktop:~/jhbuild/jhbuild$ jhbuild sanitycheck
jhbuild: install prefix (/opt/gnome) can not be created
daddara@daddara-desktop:~/jhbuild/jhbuild$ chmod 777 /opt/gnome/ -R
chmod: cannot access `/opt/gnome/': No such file or directory
daddara@daddara-desktop:~/jhbuild/jhbuild$ sudo chmod 777 /opt/gnome/ -R
chmod: cannot access `/opt/gnome/': No such file or directory
daddara@daddara-desktop:~/jhbuild/jhbuild$ jhbuild sanitycheck
jhbuild: install prefix (/opt/gnome) can not be created
daddara@daddara-desktop:~/jhbuild/jhbuild$ mkdir -p /opt/gnome
mkdir: cannot create directory `/opt/gnome': Permission denied
```

What the problem is with the installation?

Comment: You should not use the `sanitycheck` command: like the `bootstrap` command, it's not really meant to be used on modern Linux distributions. You should read the documentation on the GNOME wiki instead: https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `/opt/gnome` with `sudo mkdir`, *then* use `sudo chmod` to set its permissions. You forgot the `sudo` in your `mkdir`.

Answer (score 0):

jhbuild was also failing for me with error:

```
jhbuild: install prefix (/opt/gnome) can not be created
```

In my case, the problem was I accidentally did a `sudo make install` inside the gnome-icon-theme module, so this command created `/opt/gnome` directory and installed inside it the gnome-icon-theme files, then later I was to `jhbuild run gedit` and the aforementioned error came out, this is because jhbuild will automatically use `/opt/gnome` if it exists (for backwards compatibility), an if non-existant then will use the recommended way using `~/jhbuild/install`, you can see that [here](https://git.gnome.org/browse/jhbuild/tree/jhbuild/defaults.jhbuildrc#n37) .

So in this case, as the only files inside `/opt/gnome` were the ones I accidentally installed by my `sudo make install` command, the solution was just to delete this directory (eg. by doing `sudo rm -rf /opt/gnome`) and after that, the command `jhbuild run any-gnome-app` worked properly again.

Hopefully this answer can help people coming here from searching google for the `(/opt/gnome) can not be created` error.